# Datasnapshot is not updated even when connected to internet in my workermanager

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

With debugging I can see that it enters all of that but snapshot has an old value. I have persistency enabled in firebase database. What's wrong?

This is my code of the worker class inn which I save in Shared preferences some data. But for example it enters ref1 but snapshot has the old value.

```java
code
```

Is it not necessary to look at the details (data input, ..., job inside worker, etc).

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo my datasnapshot has the old value... it does not update it from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have disk persistence enabled and there is a value stored in the local cache, the `onDataChange` of a listener registered with `addValueEventListener` will be called twice:

1. Right away with the current value from the local cache.
2. Then again once the latest value is retrieved from the server.

There is no way to change this behavior of `addValueEventListener`. to skip #1

If you want to get the value from the server, and only fallback to the disk cache if the server isn't available, consider using the newer `get()` operation that does precisely that.

Comment: Ok. But I saw one call only in the above code. Why? Am I doing something wrong? I remove listener after waiting one time... Should I wait for two? So for example I need to add one more to the initial latch?

Comment: If your `onDataChange` only gets invoked once, either there was no cached value or there is no connection to the server, or the value from the server is the same as the cached value, or you removed the listener before the value came back from the server. I did not check the latches in your code, so can't speak to that. --- Honestly though, it seems like `get()` is much closer to what you're trying to do, so I recommend checking that out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once